Can not add my app in other apps share sheet
When I click the share option from other apps, I can see that there are other apps options like - "Edit with Videolap," "Inshot," etc. So now I want to add my app here also, like "Edit with EDpro." How can I achieve this?
Sample image included below:

When I click the share option from other apps, I can see that there are other apps options like - "Edit with Videolap," "Inshot," etc. So now I want to add my app here also, like "Edit with EDpro." How can I achieve this?

add a share extension

Added but my app not showing in this list

Ok.  The problem is probably in line 27

This is not actually a share extension, it is an Action Extension. @Paulw11

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW8
